# no find() method on xml object

Tags: javascript, xml

After extracting the tags I require from an xml document I have two set of tags that I want to iterate over. For one of the sets I get the message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Element> has no method 'find'
```

I find this strange as I get them in the same way and if I write them to the console they are there.

```
var rows = response.getElementsByTagName("row");
for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i)
{
    var northWalls = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("north");
    var westWalls = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("west");
    console.log(westWalls); //this prints as I expect

    for(var j = 0; j < northWalls.length; ++j)
    {
        var x = cellWidth * j;
        var y = cellWidth * i;
        if(i != 0 && northWalls[j].find("north").text() == false)
        {//north                
            drawWall(ctx, x, y, x + cellWidth, y);
        }
        if(j != 0 && westWalls[j].find("west").text() == false)
        {                         //this find method gives the error
            drawWall(ctx, x, y, x, y + cellWidth);
        }
    }       
}
```

Why would one of these give me this error and not the other one.

[EDIT]After the advice from @sabof I ended up with this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i)
{
    var northWalls = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("north");
    var westWalls = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("west");

    for(var j = 0; j < northWalls.length; ++j)
    {               
        var x = cellWidth * j;
        var y = cellWidth * i;

        if(i != 0 && northWalls[j].firstChild.nodeValue === "false")
        {//north        
            drawWall(ctx, x, y, x + cellWidth, y);
        }
        if(j != 0 && westWalls[j].firstChild.nodeValue === "false")
        {//west
            drawWall(ctx, x, y, x, y + cellWidth);
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) JavaScript arrays don't have a `.find` method. You are probably looking for `.indexOf`. b) `.getElementsByTagName` returns a pseudo-array, and pseudo-arrays don't have array methods.

`.indexOf` returns an index of the found element, or `-1`, if nothing is found. It can be "forced" on a pseudo array like this:

```
Array.prototype.indexOf.call(theArray, 'thing')
```

There are other errors in your code. Chances are you are confusing the API of DOM elements, with the jQuery API.

Comment: Probably because `i` is 0 on the first iteration, and the first is never executed.